# Powershell GUI, How to take password input without exposing

Tags: powershell, winforms

I have a situation I am writing a powershell GUI.

I need to take the password in a secure input.. How can I do it ?

The passwd input need to be secured in the window

below is my code

```
$Passwd                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Passwd.multiline               = $false
$Passwd.width                   = 150
$Passwd.height                  = 20
$Passwd.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(169,26)
$Passwd.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$Passwd.ForeColor               = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#7ed321")
$Passwd.BackColor               = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#000000")
```

this is the code

the passwd input nee to be secured input ?

Comment: What do you mean with "*Secured input*"? Knowing that you might *hide* the input with e.g. `$Passwd.UseSystemPasswordChar` but in will not be *secured* in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [`UseSystemPasswordChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-textbox-usesystempasswordchar) to `$true`:

```
$Passwd.UseSystemPasswordChar = $true
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried system.Windows.Forms.TextBox, it worked.

```
$Passwd                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
```